# Make a custom SSIS package to reuse

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I have created a SSIS package which is used to connect to the FTP server and retrieve all the xml files from that server. I have used mostly variables like sftp_server, username, etc., How can I make it a customisable package?

In other words, How can i plug in with other project and pass all the required fields and do the same thing there.

This is my package

[image]

Comment: I would simply copy paste it. So it belongs to the project your working on. And not a package you call from another project. It will make things unclear for you at some point. Otherwise you could call it via dtexe with parameters.

Comment: You can use config file to update your variables

Answer (score 0):

Since your screen shot looks like it's from SSIS 2012+, you can make your variables into parameters.  Then you can call the same package from multiple jobs, and in the job step where you call the package, you can go into the Configuration tab and set the values of the package parameters for that job.

So different jobs can all call the same package and all pass their own values for FTP Server, Credentials, Local Paths, etc.

This assumes you are using the Project Deployment Model that became available in 2012.  Otherwise you can do the same thing using Config files instead.